# Do I need to initial a inner class again?

Tags: android

I define a class named DetailsInfo.
Do I need to add the code:  `aDetailsInfo.thumbnails=new Bitmap();` 
Thanks!

**Class:**

```
  DetailsInfo aDetailsInfo=new DetailsInfo();

  class DetailsInfo {
           String name;
           Bitmap thumbnails;
       }
```

Comment: I don't get what you are asking for.

Comment: Please rewrite your question to better explain your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May this help you:

Buddy i think you are asking that do you need to create Object of `Bitmap` again to refer it..

I suggest you to create a `Zero argument constructor` in which you do the initialization of the Parameters that you are using in that class..
 So that whenever you create a new object of that class you will automatically create reference to the object that are specified inside that class..

**Example:**

```
class DetailsInfo {

           String name;
           Bitmap thumbnails;
           Bitmap Secondthumbnails;

         public DetailsInfo()
         {
            this.Secondthumbnails = new Bitmap();
            this.thumbnails = new Bitmap();
         }

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what 'thumbnails' is gonna be. If it's an external resource like a PNG, no.